# Orgmode checkbox-list progress in column-view

Tags: org-mode, column

I would like to have a *Progress* Column in [Column view](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-column-view-tutorial.html) that shows the [Checkbox](http://orgmode.org/manual/Checkboxes.html) count for headlines / subtasks .

I can make the count show after the subtask / headline by adding the `[/]` cookie, but I I can't make them show in the Column view.

I have tried several ways, including  the below columns, but none work:

```
* Project
    :PROPERTIES:
    :COLUMNS:  %COOKIE_DATA %[/] %boxcount{{/}}
    :COOKIE_DATA: checkbox
    :END:
** Task1
    :PROPERTIES:
    :COOKIE_DATA: checkbox
    :boxcount: [/]
    :END:
```

Now, I have found I can have a [checkbox count across tasks when manually putting checkboxes in their properties](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2009-04/msg00647.html), but I would like to know how to automatically propagate the Checkbox-list count that appears behind a headline when putting a `[X]` or `[X]` macro into column view